# two onEdit(e) functions running simulatenously on Google Sheets App Script

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am working on a project and it seems I have got 2 `onEdit(e)` functions in my script.

The first `onEdit` function checks column C for an update and enters a timestamp into column A when it is.

The second an edit function checks entries in 1 sheet and edits a cell in another sheet (and vice versa).

What im confused about is, i didn't write the first function, i found it online and forgot it was an onEdit function. Then i wrote the second function, tested, works fine. And it also works alongside the 1st edit function.

It was my understanding that you couldn't have multiple methods with the same name in Google Apps Script... is this incorrect?

Answer (score 0):

```js
function main() {
    console.log("Function 1");
}

function main() {
    console.log("Function 2");
}

main(); // Output: "Function 2"
```

As far as I can tell you can have many functions with the same name. But only last one will work. Rest functions will be ignored.

Answer (score 0):

#### Answer:

*Only one of the `onEdit()` methods will be run.*

#### Code Fix:

Assuming you have code like this:

```
function onEdit(e) {
  // code to check column C for an update and enter a timestamp into column A 
}

function onEdit(e) {
  // code to check entries in 1 sheet and edit a cell in another sheet 
}
```

You can allow both to run by renaming them and adding a new `onEdit()`:

```
function onEdit(e) {
  checkColC(e)
  checkEntries(e)
}

function checkColC(e) {
  // code to check column C for an update and enter a timestamp into column A 
}

function checkEntries(e) {
  // code to check entries in 1 sheet and edit a cell in another sheet 
}
```